# Is the "subset product" problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

The subset-sum problem is a classic NP-complete problem:

> Given a list of numbers $L$ and a target $k$, is there a subset of numbers from $L$ that sums to $k$?

A student asked me if this variant of the problem called the "subset product" problem is NP-complete:

> Given a list of numbers $L$ and a target $k$, is there a subset of numbers from $L$ whose product is $k$?

I did some searching and couldn't find any resources that talked about this problem, though perhaps I missed them.

Is the subset product problem NP-complete?

Comment: Interesting answers, but I'm wondering: Can't we reduce to Subset Sum just by taking logs of k and all the numbers?  (Maybe I should ask a separate question?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, yes, if you cannot find an answer after searching on this site and online, I suggest you post a separate question.  It is a nice question with a nice answer (hint: taking logs leaves you with something that isn't an integer; in the other direction, think about what exponentiating does to the size of the numbers), but it's a bit of a tangent and would be better in its own question.

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks, when I get time I'll do as you suggest!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A comment mentions a reduction from X3C to SUBSET PRODUCT attributed to Yao.  Given the target of the reduction it wasn't hard to guess what the reduction was likely to have been.

Definitions:

> EXACT COVER BY 3-SETS (X3C)
>
> Given a finite set $X$ with $|X|$ a multiple of 3, and a collection $C$ of 3-element subsets of $X$, does $C$ contain an exact cover $C'$ for $X$, where $C' \subseteq C$ and every element in $X$ occurs in exactly once in $C'$?
>
> SUBSET PRODUCT
>
> Given a list of numbers $L$ and a target $k$, is there a subset of numbers from $L$ whose product is $k$?

To reduce an X3C instance to a SUBSET PRODUCT instance:

1. Establish a bijective mapping between the members of $X$ and the first $|X|$ prime numbers.  Replace the members of $X$ and the $C$ subsets with the mapped primes.
2. For each subset in $C$, multiply its members together; the resulting list of products is $L$ for the SUBSET PRODUCT instance.  Because prime numbers are used for the mapping in step 1, the products are guaranteed to be equivalent iff the subsets are equivalent by the [unique factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).
3. Multiply the members of $X$ together; the resulting product is the value $k$ for the SUBSET PRODUCT instance.

The prime factors of $k$ are exactly the members of $X$.  The prime factors of the numbers in $L$ correspond exactly to the members of the $C$ subsets.  Therefore any solution to the new SUBSET PRODUCT instance can be transformed into a X3C solution by mapping the solution members of $L$ back to the subsets in $C$.

Each of the 3 transformation steps involves operations that are polynomial to the size of the input $|X|$ or the size of a member of $X$.  The first $|X|$ primes can be generated in time O($|X|$) using the sieve of Eratosthenes and are guaranteed to fit into $O(|X|^2 \ln |X|)$ space by the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number).

Comment: +1, but for the reduction to go through I think we require that the first |X| prime numbers can be represented in a number of bits that is polynomial in |X| -- am I right about this, and if so, do we have that guarantee?

Comment: Excellent point.  I've added a paragraph to address that.

Comment: Thanks, that theorem cements it!  Not to nitpick, but according to the page you linked to, the kth prime number is approximately k log k, and given that the Sieve of Eratosthenes apparently calculates all primes up to n in time [O(n log log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity), substituting n = k log k appears to give a time of O(k*log(k)*log(log(k log k))), rather than O(k) (your O(|X|)), to calculate the first k primes that way.

Comment: Kyle Jones, isn't it critical that step 3 will create a number $k$ of exponential size? Is this reduction really of polynomial time?

Comment: @user1742364 No, because computing $k$ doesn't require an exponential number of operations or require storing an exponential number of bits.  Computing $k$ requires $|X|$ multiplications and multiplication is at worst a $O(n^2)$ operation.  While $k$ will be exponentially larger than the largest prime $P$ in $X$, the number of bits needed to store $k$ will be $O(\log P)$.

Comment: The product of the first $n$ prime number is of the order $e^{n \log n}$. See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Comment: Note that contrary to G&J's claim of strong NP-hardness, this reduction only establishes weak NP-hardness, because of the size of the target product.  Johnson acknowledged the error in the [first NP-completeness column (page 10)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512145415/http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/columns/col1.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

According to [[1](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~ped/teachadmin/COMP202/annotated_np.html)]: Yes it is

I also cite the same reference: 
Comments: There is a subtle technical distinction between this and Problem 42: the former case has a pseudo-efficient algorithm obtained by allowing numbers to be represented in unary; unless all NP-complete problems can be solved by fast algorithms, however, the Subset Product Problem, cannot be solved by `efficient' methods using even this unreasonable input representation.

have a look on [2] for a reduction. 
[2]: Fellows, Michael, and Neal Koblitz. "Fixed-parameter complexity and cryptography." Applied Algebra, Algebraic Algorithms and Error-Correcting Codes (1993): 121-131.

Comment: An actual reduction or citation in a journal article would be nice, if possible.

Comment: @templatetypedef In Garey and Johnson, the reduction is to the exact cover by 3 sets. Due to private communication with Yao.

Comment: The reduction in the cryptography paper is for a different problem, in which the target product is replaced by congruence with a target number modulo a modulus given in the instance.  (Though if I understand the proof correctly, they only get weak hardness anyway because the modulus is exponential in magnitude.)